# Parameters in odd locations in Prepared Statements in Microsoft SQL and JDBC

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, scala, jdbc

So I have the following statement I'm executing in Microsoft SQL 2008:

```
  SELECT
  'UTC' AS timezone,
  rel.unique_id AS relay,sns.unique_id AS sensor,
  dateadd(MINUTE, datediff(MINUTE, 0, pak.rtime) / ? * ?, 0) AS time,
  SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,dat.data)) AS total
  FROM sensor_data dat
   LEFT OUTER JOIN data_package pak ON dat.package_id = pak.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN relays rel ON pak.relay_id = rel.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN sensors sns ON dat.sensor_id = sns.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN sensor_types typ ON sns.sensor_type = typ.id
   WHERE typ.name = 'Volume' AND dateadd(MINUTE, datediff(MINUTE, 0, pak.rtime) / ? * ?, 0) > ? AND dateadd(MINUTE, datediff(MINUTE, 0, pak.rtime) / ? * ?, 0) < ?
   GROUP BY rel.unique_id,sns.unique_id, dateadd(MINUTE, datediff(MINUTE, 0, pak.rtime) / ? * ?, 0)
   ORDER BY time,relay,sensor
```

If I set the parameters using the jTDS/JDBC driver like so:

```
Parameter 1: 15
Parameter 2: 15
Parameter 3: 15
Parameter 4: 15
Parameter 5: 2011-10-31 20:00:00
Parameter 6: 15
Parameter 7: 15
Parameter 8: 2011-12-29 19:00:00
Parameter 9: 15
Parameter 10: 15
```

I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'data_package.rtime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

If I manually put in 15s in all those ? spaces, the query works perfect with just the dates as parameters.

1) Is there anyway to parametrize the interval value (15 in this case) or do I just have to escape it and search and replace that before it becomes a prepared statement (and if that's true, what's the best way to escape that parameter in Scala/Java)

2) Can I keep from repeating the dateadd(datediff()) section three times? I know I can't reference "time" in the WHERE clause, but is there some other way to specify that somewhere to make it cleaner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your select looks like:

```
SELECT dateadd(MINUTE, datediff(MINUTE, 0, pak.rtime) / ? * ?, 0) AS time,
```

And your group by:

```
GROUP BY dateadd(MINUTE, datediff(MINUTE, 0, pak.rtime) / ? * ?, 0)
```

With the `?` replaced by constants, these two are identical.

But using unnamed parameters introduces a problem.  The select version uses parameter 1 and 2, and the group by version uses parameter 9 and 10.  And SQL Server does not now that those parameters are always equal.  So it throws an error.

You can avoid this situation by computing the field in a subquery:

```
left join
        (
        select  *
        ,       dateadd(MINUTE, datediff(MINUTE, 0, pak.rtime) / ? * ?, 0) as X
        from    data_package
        ) as pak
on      dat.package_id = pak.id
```

You can now refer to `pak.X` in other parts of your query, like:

```
group by
        pak.X
```

Comment: No need to use a subquery, a derived table should be fine

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: What's the difference between a derived table and a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Andomar is right that the problem is use of parameters in your GROUP BY, but I believe his solution might be over-complicated.  Easier, I would think, to write:

```
SELECT
  'UTC' AS timezone,
  rel.unique_id AS relay,sns.unique_id AS sensor,
  dateadd(MINUTE, datediff(MINUTE, 0, pak.rtime) / ? * ?, 0) AS time,
  SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,dat.data)) AS total
  FROM sensor_data dat
   LEFT OUTER JOIN data_package pak ON dat.package_id = pak.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN relays rel ON pak.relay_id = rel.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN sensors sns ON dat.sensor_id = sns.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN sensor_types typ ON sns.sensor_type = typ.id
   WHERE typ.name = 'Volume' AND dateadd(MINUTE, datediff(MINUTE, 0, pak.rtime) / ? * ?, 0) > ? AND dateadd(MINUTE, datediff(MINUTE, 0, pak.rtime) / ? * ?, 0) < ?
   GROUP BY rel.unique_id,sns.unique_id, time
   ORDER BY time,relay,sensor
```

(On the other hand, since in your particular case, you are using the exact same expression in the WHERE, maybe the subquery *would* be better.)